# psql query not returning proper results?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, psql

```
var searchValue = 'shahid';
var query = ("select * from students where name ilike '%"+searchValue+"%'");
```

This is my psql query, but it is not returning any values. So that I just console the query to know the execution.

The query is executing as:

```
select * from students where name ilike 'hahid%'
```

When I capitalize the first letter of search value (Shahid), it's executing perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass in the upper case you should convert the variable searchValue
eg.

```
var newSearchValue = (select initcatp(searchValue)) ;
```

This will convert 'shahid' to 'Shahid' Then use this in your query variable.

Answer (score 0):

This, lacking a '%' on the left hand side, will only match thing that *start with* `hahid`

```
 select * from students where name ilike 'hahid%'
```

It's not the same as this

```
select * from students where name ilike 'Shahid%'
```

which will match only things that *start with* `Shahid`. Now if you want something that will match anything with `hahid` then you want

```
 select * from students where name ilike '%hahid%'
```

BTW, your example is extremely insecure if searchValue comes from I/O (user, file, network etc).